# ember.js pulling from multiple model stores in a single template

Tags: ember.js

i'm trying to learn how to create a form that draws from several models.

For example, a `Person` form that a user can specify their name, city, what `Company`(separate model) they belong to, what `Group`s(separate model) they're in, what `Car`(separate model) they drive, etc. I can't find any documentation on how this can be achieved.

In all the examples i've seen, the route is responsible for telling the template which singular model type to use. I have no idea how to create a dropdown or typeahead that pulls from a different model repository.

How can i accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to accomplish this.

(1) Add a property to your controller that returns the necessary records for your drop down.

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/AqimiFI/4/edit

```
 setupController: function(controller, model) {
   this._super(controller, model);

   // set an empty array
   controller.set('states', []);

   this.get('store').find('state').then(function(states){
     //once the states are resolved set the states to the records
     controller.set('states', states);
   });
  }
```

(2) At some point in your application (wherever it seems appropriate) in one of your routes create a controller for the items in question and set the model of that controller to the items, then use needs.  I prefer this method, because you can use that controller all over the application add logic to it and have it be shared etc...

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/AqimiFI/5/edit

```
setupController: function(controller, model) {
  this._super(controller, model);

  var states = this.controllerFor('states');
  states.set('model', this.get('store').find('state'));
}

App.ApplicationController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  needs:['states'],

  states:function(){
    return this.get('controllers.states');
  }.property('controllers.states')
});
```

In this example, I created a states controller in the application route.  This isn't tying it to the application controller/route at all, it was just a hook early on that I could take advantage of for creating the controller to hold the data.

In order to access a controller from another controller you must specify that you need it (needs:['states']).

The states property is returning the states controller (it's important to remember that an array controller, and controllers in general, in ember are just decorators on their models).  Ember will proxy all get/set calls down to the model (if they don't exist on the controller).  So when I'm returning the states controller really you could think of it as just returning the model, which is the array of states.

So, you could try and set the property right on the controller, but it probably wouldn't work as expected.  I'm taking advantage of the fact that I know if I set a promise on the model it will actually resolve that promise and replace the model with the result of that promise.  It's just a little closer to the expected behavior of manually creating controllers.

Comment: wow...this is confusing. Let me try to translate what i think is going on. In the `ApplicationRoute` your specifying the model for the `StatesController`, you're saying you need the `StatesController` in the `ApplicationController`. The `states` property on the `ApplicationController` is returning the model from the `StatesController` from `this.get('controllers.states')`? If that's correct could you have defined the model for the `StatesController` directly in the `StatesController` and not in the `ApplicationRoute`?

Comment: Hah, it might have been a little less confusing if I used more than one controller, let me see if I can break down your statement.

Comment: check out the statement above, and shoot me anymore questions if you need more clarification.

Comment: I don't understand why there still needs to be a definition for a `StatesController` if you're creating it in the `ApplicationRoute`. If i delete `StatesController` in the jsfiddle, it breaks. If you have to actually define the `StatesController`, why wouldn't you return the models from there? like this http://emberjs.jsbin.com/AqimiFI/7/edit ...doesn't work though, i don't understand why

Comment: Firstly: you can't call controllerFor without a definition (Ember wouldn't know if you wanted an extended version of Controller, ObjectController, or ArrayController.

Comment: so there is two problems with that, you are defining model as a function, not a property (you need to add .property()) at the end of it

Comment: *are two problems, secondly when you define it like that on the controller it doesn't properly get wired to the controller.  So the controller is no longer decorating it, it's essentially just a random controller, with a random property on it.

Comment: And then your controller isn't really an array controller, since the model backing it never really got set.

Comment: So to have the model properly wired to the controller, it must be done outside of the controller? from another controller or route? or could you use `this.set('model', this.get('store').find('state'))` in the `setupController` method?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40050/discussion-between-kingpin2k-and-david)